# Perform action whenever the slider slides

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I have a simple date slider implemented in codepen with Angularjs materials below. 
http://codepen.io/helpme/pen/MaGpPa

```
.sliderdemoBasicUsage input[type="number"] {
  text-align: center; }
```

I would like this slider to perform a simple action whenever the slide is moved. For example, I would like a window alert to appear "Slider moved" whenever the slide is moved. I am still at a loss how this can be done after visiting the documentation https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSlider

How can this be done, if possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can observe a specific component property or state as it changes with $scope.$watch:

I modified your Codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpGdEM

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.month = 4;

  $scope.$watch('month', function(val) {
    // read the value of month and perform action
    if (val === 9) alert('This is September');
  });
});
```

Comment: I have my own Codepen. But there is something wrong. Would you mind telling me what is wrong. http://codepen.io/helpme/pen/xwzjrw

Comment: Marked as answer. Thanks! Great answer.

Comment: Ah! You are missing the $ before scope. make it $scope.$watch